# I'm trying to get the Text widget functions to work properly in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text, parameters, widget

I'm trying to take input text in the tkinter text widget and transfer it to another text widget object line by line.

I've tried passing literals to the text.get(start index, end index) and text.insert(index, stringToInsert)

```
from tkinter import *
import re 

class TextCompiler:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.a = 1.0

        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.topLabel = Label(master, text = "Enter text to be compiled: ", bg = "green", fg = "black")
        self.topLabel.pack(side = TOP)

        self.windowIn = Text(master, state=NORMAL, height=20, width=30)
        self.windowIn.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.windowOut = Text(master, height=20, width=30)
        self.windowOut.pack(side = RIGHT)

        self.printButton = Button(self.frame, text="Compile next line?", command = lambda: self.transferPrint(self.a))
        self.printButton.pack(side = BOTTOM)

        self.quitButton = Button(self.frame, text="Quit", command=lambda: self.quitStuff(master))
        self.quitButton.pack(side = BOTTOM)

    def transferPrint(self, a):
            b = self.a + 0.30
            endOfLine = "{0:.2f}".format(b)
            inputText = self.windowIn.get(self.a, endOfLine)
            self.windowOut.insert(self.a, inputText)
            self.a = self.a + 1.0

    def quitStuff(self, master):
        self.frame.quit()
        master.destroy()

root = Tk()
TextCompiler(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I need it to copy one full line and transfer it to second text window at a time at the click of "Compile next line?" button. So far I had it capturing one line of code and then not pasting it properly. It would paste to the end of the previous string. Then when I put in one FULL line of text and a second line of text it pasted incompletely.
So we should get(1.0, 1.30)
and insert(1.0, string)
then get(2.0, 2.30)
insert(2.0, string)
get(3.0, 3.30)
insert(3.0, string)
and so on.. but its ignoring literal changes to the parameters and as said before not pasting full lines of texts properly...

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. First is that indexes aren't floating-point numbers and you shouldn't be doing floating point math on them. Indexes are strings of the form *line*.*character*.

For example, in floating-point numbers, 1.3 and 1.30 are identical. As indexes, "1.3" represents the third character on line 1, and "1.30" represents the thirtieth character on line one.

Additionally, you are neglecting to copy the newline at the end of each line. You can't insert on line 2 in the other window unless line 1 ends with a newline, you can't insert on line 3 if line two doesn't end in a newline, and so on.

I don't know what your intent is, so it's hard to recommend a solution. For example, do you really want to only copy the first 30 characters of a line, or is your goal to copy the whole line?

If you want only the first 30 characters of a line and copy it to a new line in the other window, you need to insert a newline when you copy it over. For example:

```
self.windowOut.insert("end", inputText+"\n")
```

If your goal is just to copy entire lines, you can use a modifier to copy the entire line plus the trailing newline. Or, copy just the entire line without the newline, and like above you can append a newline when copying it over.

Here's how to get the full line:

```
end = "{} lineend".format(self.a)
```

Here's how to get the full line plus the trailing newline:

```
end = "{} lineend+1c".format(self.a)
```

Comment: Okay I got this now. Everything works. IF. I don't just keep typing in the input widget at the end of a line. In my code it is 30 chars wide. After the 30th char if I hit return and I'm guessing, insert a newline char implicitly, then it will not break the copy of the next line. Otherwise it doesn't "see" the next line in the input widget.

Comment: but if I use your "end" method It grabs everything up to the next newline. not what I want. I want just to grab text one line at a time.

Comment: @ChristianGalleisky the text widget will allow you to do whatever you want. You just need to understand that you can't create a new line in a text widget without actually inserting a newline character. You have complete control over what you copy and what you insert, with newlines or without newlines, as long as you follow the documented behavior of the text widget.

Comment: Are you aware that even if you make the widget 30 characters wide, it's possible to to enter more than 30 characters on a line. The width of the widget only determines the visual appearance. It doesn't change how much data can exist on a line.

Comment: Yesyes. learned this yesterday later. a line is DEFINED as up to a newline char. Right?

Comment: @ChristianGalleisky: well, "line" can mean different things in different contexts. In the context of your question, I personally interpret "line" to mean all of the text plus the trailing newline. The text widget actually has the concept of  _logical lines_ and _display lines_. If a single line of text wraps, it is a single logical line but two or more _display lines_.